# When I apply IK to the armature the knee moves weirdly

Tags: armature

Im following this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XkiWBSSuxLw but the knees never seem to work. Instead of moving like they want to, they rotate. I have tried adding more geometry but that doesn't work. My knees are bent slightly forward.
I have tried this tutorial twice with two different models.
here is my current blend file: https://pasteall.org/blend/a15407ee54f94d9fb89913873e906561

Answer (score 2):

Your pole targets are too close to the knees. The knees will always point towards the pole targets, that's why they rotate as soon as they go beyond, to avoid that,just move the pole targets a bit forward:

[image]