# Why is my armature causing the knees to lock?

Tags: armature, inverse-kinematics

I made a full armature for my character and when I tested the movements, I noticed that the knees kinda move towards each other instead of moving straight forward.I'm not quite sure how to fix it so if anyone can identify the problem that'd be great. I used inverse kinematics and included a picture of the relations if that helps. [image]

[image]

Comment: maybe you have inverted the pole targets? please share your file: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: That is the reason. I found a page that solved my problem almost immediately after I posted this. https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/232915/when-i-apply-ik-to-the-armature-the-knee-moves-weirdly

Comment: oh ok, i was the one that answered  ;)

Comment: Wow! So you were! Didn't notice, sorry